# Recursive JSON tree does not work when parsed

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, object, nestjs

So I am making a file tree list structure in the front end and it produces a JSON tree. Every time I modify the tree I post the object to the backend in order to store the new leafs that I add. Here is the tree structure that I am passing to the backend

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": "1",
        "isLeaf": true,
        "_id": "626584371ff07c474d6da2b3",
        "pid": 0,
        "isRoot": true,
        "isActive": true,
        "type": "testSite2",
        "name": "testSite2",
        "ownerUid": "XeqTkJ5VUnWFYWK7bKWXeQ58yLF3",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-24T17:09:11.877Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-24T17:09:11.877Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "3",
        "isLeaf": false,
        "_id": "626584a31ff07c474d6da2f3",
        "pid": 0,
        "isRoot": true,
        "isActive": true,
        "type": "testSite2",
        "name": "todelete",
        "ownerUid": "XeqTkJ5VUnWFYWK7bKWXeQ58yLF3",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-24T17:10:59.897Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-24T17:10:59.897Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "isLeaf": true,
                "name": "test",
                "ownerUiD": "XeqTkJ5VUnWFYWK7bKWXeQ58yLF3",
                "type": "testType",
                "id": 1650988619073,
                "isRoot": "false",
                "isActive": "true",
                "pid": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I send this as is to the backend it returns an error 400 so I try to resolve by parsing it before I pass, whenever I do JSON.parse() on the structure it returns this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

I tried verifying my JSON structure and it passes as a valid JSON, I tried to stringify it and it returns the same error. What am I missing here?

Comment: There's no way to know w/o additional information. Since this is valid JSON the problem lies elsewhere. So without knowing how you're sending it, how you're receiving it, etc it's impossible to help. It'd probably make sense to inspect what you're trying to parse as a first step.

Comment: are you 100% sure that the variable or content you are parsing as JSON is actually a JSON string? I mean we see that you have a JSON string here, but we do not see your code, without that it is hard to tell.

Comment: I've seen this before when there's' an extra parse... the second one errs because it gets the object resulting from the first parse instead of a string that it expects.

Comment: The error virtually always means that it's `[object Object]` string that was passed instead of JSON. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @danh I have to parse it twice since I'm using Vue. Vue tends to add the observers in the objects, to remove it I have to do JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)) as instructed by Evan You in Github forums

Comment: @Jam, (1) why is the object getting the observers bound in the first place (if they aren't wanted... they usually are wanted if the object is referred to in the render), (2) removing observers in the way you describe must entail first stringifying, ,then parsing, (3) whenever I see that pattern - stringify then parse - my first reaction is that something is probably being done thoughtlessly and  probably wastefully. (4) how can we talk about this without code?

Comment: This typically happens when you pass an object to a method which expects a string. What happens there is that the object is cast as `string` by running [Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on it which, in the case of objects, returns the string `"[object Object]"` which, obviously, is not valid JSON. Use `console.log()` to output the contents of your data through the entire trace of methods, making sure it is what you think it should be throughout each step. You'll find the culprit soon enough.

Comment: Needless to point out, if you can't figure it out on your own, use codesandbox.io (or similar) to repro what you have. Even if you're not able to spot the bug, others might, as long as they are able to run/inspect your code. Pay close attention to the payload of your server requests and their responses. Most likely, you are looking for one ***unnecessary*** `JSON.parse()` call. Have a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/a2tmh0fk/) (e.g: `JSON.parse()` expects a string and will turn any object into `"[object Object]"`). When not sure, use `console.log(typeof myObj)`.

Comment: I apologize to everyone, I have investigated further and it appears that the problem is on the backend. Sometimes I forget that my app is using NestJs and it is very strict on the types which is why it is responding with 400. The problem does not lie in the frontend rather it's the handling of the data in the backend. Thank you everone for the insights

Answer (score 1):

The reason has to be because the method expects a string and you have returned a object to it ,thats when this error occurs.Do check your code for any conversions from object to string in previous lines.If what you require is for the data to be sent as a object instead of a string,you can send it without parsing it.